# Can you use ng-click with ui-sref?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Can I do this?

```
<button ng-click='vm.foo()' ui-sref='state'>test</button>
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What happens?

Comment: Your `ng-click` is likely tied to a controller, will that controller be around in your new state?

Comment: @JamesAllardice just doing a little ask+answer for people to reference in the future.

Comment: I think the whole point of this was to create a self answered question (which is perfectly acceptable).  However, since the question was rather vague, it appears to have been downvoted.  Aside from that, I don't really think that the edit which moved the Answer into the question body is particularly appropriate.  It may be more appropriate to expand the question to provide a bit more information or use cases.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes. `ngClick` will run, and then you'll transition to your state.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/0oLK2QGqTO4mxWLigBGX?p=preview) (updated and working thanks to [marioosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32186462/can-you-use-ng-click-with-ui-sref/32186495?noredirect=1#comment79388246_32186495))

However, if you have an `$event.preventDefault()` in `ngClick`, it won't transition you to your state.

Full code example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='app'>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-router@*" data-semver="0.2.15" src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.15/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller='MainController as vm'>
    <ul>
      <li><a ui-sref='home'>home</a></li>
      <li><a ui-sref='one' ng-click='vm.test()'>one</a></li>
      <li><a ui-sref='two'>two</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div ui-view></div>
  </body>

</html>

angular
  .module('app', ['ui.router'])
  .config(config)
  .controller('MainController', MainController)
;

function config($locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    .state('one', {
      url: '/one',
      templateUrl: 'one.html'
    })
    .state('two', {
      url: '/two',
      templateUrl: 'two.html'
    })
  ;
}

function MainController($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.test = function() {
    alert('test');
    console.log('test');
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use ng-show / ng-if and render a different anchor tag with a different ui-sref?

Comment: *"if you have an `$event.preventDefault()` in `ngClick`"*, it also **will** transit to a new state for me.

Comment: `$event.stopPropagation()` in a `ng-click` function could help

Comment: Fixed and working example [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/0oLK2QGqTO4mxWLigBGX?p=preview)

Comment: @patrick Fixed thanks to @marioosh. There was a problem with the `templateUrl` path related to Plunker.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko `$event.preventDefault()` seems to be [working](http://plnkr.co/edit/H0mQycIWYacObnJ3woOd?p=preview) for me.

Comment: In my case, I *thought* this wasn't working, but our ng-click was setting a variable which was making the button disabled, which in turn prevented the ui-sref link from firing. So now wrapping that call in a timeout, so the button gets disabled after the ui-sref fires.