# Can we use ng-click with ui-sref

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

Can we use ng-click with ui-sref?

I am using **angular 1.5.5** with **ui-router latest version 1.0.3**.

```
<a ui-sref="sidebarMenuController.sidebarMenuRoute" ui-sref-active="sidebarActive" ng-click="sidebarMenuController.onMenuClick(sidebarMenuController.sidebarMenuData)">
         {{sidebarMenuController.sidebarMenuData.displayName}} 
</a>
```

When I use the above code, ng-click event is getting fired but ui-sref router state is not getting activated nor does the ui-sref-active class getting applied.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/32186462/8317956

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you use ng-click with ui-sref?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32186462/can-you-use-ng-click-with-ui-sref)

Answer (score 0):

use `$state.go()`

use `ng-click="sidebarMenuController.onMenuClick(sidebarMenuController.sidebarMenuData,'sidebarActive')"` and in controller use  `$state.go('sidebarActive');`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `$state.go`.

So make a function first:

**Controller**

```
//Do not forget to inject $state..

 function goTo(){
    //other stuff goes here...
    $state.go('sidebarMenuController.sidebarMenuRoute'); //this is your route...
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<a ng-click="gotTo()">Click here..</a>
```

Comment: If we use $state.go() how will ui-sref-active will work with this function? then in this case, we will have to write an handler for class activation which i dont want to do as i would like to have ui-sref and its facilities/privilages like ui-sref-active which directly activates all the parent menus.